# How to use PreferenceFragmentCompat with ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-preferences

Everything comes ready when I create a swipePager with tablelayout project in android studio. This is definitely easy.

However, I want to put a button in onOptionsMenuItem which opens settingsFragment but my settingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat.
Viewpager is working already so it is not working.

I tried

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragmentS1)
      .commit();
```

It is not working because viewPager is using R.id.frame_container and when I click the button nothing happens.